# covariance terms for random effects model

Tags: model, intercept, effects

I have a random effects model with two groups.
$$
y_i = \alpha_{j[i]} + \gamma_{k[i]}+\epsilon_i
$$
Where $j[i]$ and $k[i]$ denotes the group memberships for individual $i$.

In R, I can estimate $\sigma^2_j$ and $\sigma^2_k$ using `lme` from the `nlme` package or `lmer` from `lme4`. However I'm unable to estimate the covariance, $\sigma_{k,j}$ between the two groups. My understanding is that `lmer` simply assumes the covariance is zero. Is this correct?

Using `nlme` I get a strange error. I, perhaps naively, thought that the following would work:

```
library(nlme)

res <- lme(mpg ~ 1, random = list(cyl = ~ 1, am = ~ 1), data = mtcars)
getVarCov(res)
```

However, I get the error

```
Error in getVarCov.lme(res) : 
  not implemented for multiple levels of nesting
```

Can't tell why this error appears. Have I specified the model in lme() incorrectly?
In sum, how can I estimate $\sigma_{k, j}$ ?

Comment: I'm familiar with mixed models, but not `nlme` syntax specifically. However, two things to note. 1) `summary(res)` shows that the model you've defined nests `am` within `cyl`, which is not what you have defined in your equation. 2) in the equation in your question, it assumes that the normal R.V. associated with $\alpha$ and the other normal associated with $\beta$ are independent, by default. Hopefully that gives you a place to get started or someone else can answer in more detail later.